# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'

Tags: python, pyenv

When I try to install a python version using pyenv, I get the following error:

```
$ pyenv install 3.5.7
Downloading Python-3.5.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.7/Python-3.5.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.7...

BUILD FAILED (CentOS release 6.10 (Final) using python-build 1.2.13)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20190726132219.7116
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20190726132219.7116.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190726132219.7116/Python-3.5.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190726132219.7116/Python-3.5.7/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190726132219.7116/Python-3.5.7/Lib/tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190726132219.7116/Python-3.5.7/Lib/random.py", line 41, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: No module named 'math'
make: *** [Makefile:1048: install] Error 1
```

- Docker image: [Holy Build Box x64](https://github.com/phusion/holy-build-box)
- Tried with python 3.5.7 / 3.6.9 / 3.7.4
- Logs:
  [python-build.20190726131154.23161.log](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/files/3435894/python-build.20190726131154.23161.log)

Comment: Just came across this error on `Ubuntu 18.04 using python-build 20180424`... did you find a solution?

Comment: I also have this problem. This is strange. `python -c 'import math'` works as expected.

Comment: This seems to happen more-often-than-usual on platforms such as Cygwin. So, I'm expecting it to be some sort of library incompatibility / inconsistency, somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

My issue on mac was because I uncommented `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` in the .zshrc file

Comment: This was my issue. New mac, old .zshrc. [Discussion here of the proper value of ARCHFLAGS on apple silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908116/correct-archflags-value-on-apple-silicon)

Answer (score 0):

My python system version was pointing to an anaconda binary instead of the `/usr/bin/python`, [uninstalling anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) worked for me.

Note I also had to remove it from my $PATH, and restart my shell, otherwise the installer looks for gcc in the now deleted anaconda directory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the pip knows where it is looking for the installed files; if the files have been deleted, corrupted, or saved in another area, Python won't hesitate to throw up an error message.