# Correct ARCHFLAGS value on Apple Silicon?

Tags: macos, shell, apple-silicon

On my previous, Intel-based Mac, I used to include

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

in my shell resource file. What's the correct compilation flag on the new ARM-based Apple silicon? `arm`? `arm64`? `arm-64`? `arm_64`? There doesn't seem to be a lot of resources out there yet, any pointers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a long discussion [over here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20989) on this topic. Long story short, they're agreeing on trusting `uname -m` to provide the correct architecture name.

This returns `arm64`,  and given lack of evidence to the contrary, is probably the correct value.

Comment: `$ uname -m` returns `arm64`

does it make sense to set it in .bashrc/.zshrc?
`export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  # or what is the correct value for m2?`

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac silicon with an M2 processor, `uname -m` yields `aarch64` and not `arm64`. This is also reflected under Ubuntu installed as a VM in the filesystem structure with directories `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`

Correction: this is under Ubuntu as a VM on a Mac with a M2 processor. ON Mac itself, it does yield `arm64`

Comment: Interesting. My M1 MacBook Pro still returns arm64 for uname -m, so it seems this value isn't consistent across all macs with the M* architecture.

Comment: Correction. I was talking under Ubuntu as a VM, but you are correct. On the Mac itself, which I just did, `uname -m` does produce `arm64`